# SQL getting data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, database

I have 3 different tables:

Messages, Comments and Avatar.

What I would like to do is the following:
Get all Messages in the database, counting for each message the comments and showing the avatar of each user.

This is how the tables are built:

Messages -> messages_id, user_id, title, message

Comments -> comments_id, messages_id, comment

Avatar -> avatar_id, user_id, avatar

I tried the following:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(comments.comments_id) AS commentCount
FROM messages
LEFT JOIN comments ON messages.messages_id = comments.messages_id
LEFT JOIN avatar on messages.user_id = avatar.user_id
```

But I get only one row for the messages, the rest is not visible.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `GROUP BY`:

```
  SELECT messages_id
       , title
       , message
       , user_id
       , avatar_id
       , avatar
       , count(*) as commentCount
    FROM messages
   inner join avatar on messages.user_id = avatar.user_id
    left join comments on messages.messages_id = comments.messages_id
GROUP BY messages_id
```

This should work if:

- `messages_id` is unique in `messages`
- `user_id` is unique in `avatar`

Otherwise you need to specify the value you want to get.

Edited:

I wrote `inner join` for `avatar`table thinking in that all users have an avatar. If this is not true should be `left join` like in your query.

**Second try**

Maybe the error was that the `group by` should be `messages.messages_id` instead of `messages_id`. In fact in others RDMBS this is an error:

> ERROR: column reference "messages_id" is ambiguous

I'm going to be more precise:

```
  SELECT m.messages_id    as id
       , min(m.title)     as title
       , min(m.message)   as message
       , min(m.user_id)   as user_id
       , min(a.avatar_id) as avatar_id
       , min(a.avatar)    as avatar
       , count(c.comments_id) as commentCount
    FROM messages as m
    left join avatar as a on m.user_id = a.user_id
    left join comments as c on m.messages_id = c.messages_id
GROUP BY m.messages_id
```

All the `min`could be deleted in MySQL if you are sure there is only one value. In standard SQL you must choose the value you want, if there is only one you can type `min` or `max`.

I change join with avatar to be `left join`. Probably not all users have an avatar.

Comment: Thanks David for your reply. But I still get only one message instead of the 2 messages I have in my database.

Messages_id is indeed unique in messages and user_id is unique in avatar. 

Maybe I need to specify that not all messages have comments.

Comment: @moonwalker check the second query I wrote. If doesn't work would be helpful to have an example of table data, expected output and real output.

Comment: Thanks a lot David. Your second solution works great. I'm going to study it and try to understand what I did wrong.